# Analytic continuation of a certain Euler product

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

What is known about analytic continuation of the following product ($\forall p:u_p\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|u_p |\leq 1$):

$\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb{P}}  
\left(
1-u_p p^{-s}
\right)^{-1}$

Clearly, I am not asking this in full generality. Every method that works for an example $\{u_p\}$ is welcome.

The only reference I could find is:
RYAVEC: THE ANALYTIC CONTINUATION OF EULER PRODUCTS WITH APPLICATIONS TO ASYMPTOTIC FORMULAE. Central here is the Lemma on page 612:

Lemma: Let $c$ and $z$ be complex numbers satisfying $|cz| < 1$ and $|z| < 1$.
Then there exist complex numbers $h(m,c)$, $m = 1, 2,\ldots$ so that the equation

$\left(
1- c z
\right)^{-1} = 
\prod\limits_{m=1}^\infty  
\left(\frac{1+z^m}{1-z^m}\right)^{h(m,c)}$
holds.

This then is used to express products like $\prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb{P}}  
\left(
1-u_p p^{-s}
\right)^{-1}$ in terms of $\zeta(ms)$ (Riemann $\zeta$-function). Any other known attempts?