# Analytic continuation of Euler product $\phi(s)=\prod_p(1+p^{-s})^{-1}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

I am actually interested in the analytic continuation of $\phi_w(s)=\prod_p(1+w\cdot p^{-s})^{-1}$. Here $w$ is rational, or the imaginary unit multiplied by a rational. Consider for now that $w=1$. Of course,

$$\phi(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda(k)}{k^s}=\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)},$$

where $\lambda$ is the Louisville function, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function). It is known that $\lambda(k)=\pm 1$, being equal to $1$ half of the time, and $-1$ half of the time. The function $\phi(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s)>1$. But what about $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$?

**Question**: Does $\phi$ have an analytic continuation to $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$? The closest reference I could find is [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300560/analytic-continuation-of-euler-product-prod-p-1-e-2-pi-i-p-alphap).

In the end, I am interested in the product $\rho(s)=\eta(s)\phi^*(s)$ where $\eta$ (the Dirichlet eta function) is the analytic continuation of $\zeta$, and $\phi^*$ is the analytic continuation of $\phi$, and thus $\rho$ is analytic. I'd like to say something about the zeros of $|\rho(s)|^2$ in $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)<1$, by looking at the zeroes of $\eta$ and $\phi^*$ separately, more specifically in the product expression. The Riemann hypothesis probably implies it has none, thus also my interest in a case like $w=i$ (the imaginary unit) where $\eta_w$ has known zeroes $s=(\log i)/(\log p_k)$ for any prime $p_k$ (see note at the bottom), but the product cancels them out:

$$(1-i p_k^{-s})(1+i p_k^{-s})=1+p_k^{-2s}.$$

Anyway, before even contemplating studying this problem, the first step is to get an analytic continuation of $\phi$, thus my question. Proving that the series for $\phi(s)$ convergences if (say) $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$ would solve this issue. However I remember reading that proving this is as hard as proving RH (the Riemann hypothesis). If that is the case, there is no point for me to dig deeper into this.

**Note**:

The function $\eta_w(s)$ is the analytic continuation of $\prod_p (1-w\cdot p^{-s})^{-1}$.

Comment: $\zeta(2s)$ is analytic and nonzero for $\Re s>1/2$. In addition, $\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic for $\Re s>1/2$. Hence $\phi(s)$ is analytic for $\Re s>1/2$ if and only if $\zeta(s)$ is nonzero for $\Re s>1/2$. The last condition is the Riemann Hypothesis. I voted to close, because this question is not appropriate at this site (asking for the validity of a well-known conjecture).

Comment: @GHf : We have $|\sum_{k>1} \lambda(k)/k|<\pi^2/6$, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198404/bound-on-a-scaled-sum-of-the-liouville-function. This suggests that $\phi(s)$ is defined at $s=1$. I am wondering if convergence of the series for $\phi(s)$ can be handled using the Dirichlet test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). After all, convergence for $\eta(s)$ (where $\lambda(k)$ is replaced by $(-1)^{k+1}$ has been proved, using the Dirichlet test if I remember correctly, up to $\Re(s)>0$.

Comment: Another related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294524/analytic-continuation-of-a-certain-euler-product

Comment: In the end, it depends on how long a run of successive $\lambda(k)\cos(t\log k)$ can all be positive (or negative). The same way that it depends for the series $\eta(s)$ on how long a run of successive $(-1)^{k+1}\cos(t\log k)$ can all be positive (or negative) for the convergence test to work. Maybe for $\phi(s)$ is it equivalent to RH, or maybe not. For $\eta(s)$, it is far easier to handle than RH, and has a solution, which is why we know $\eta(s)$ converges and is analytic if $\Re(s)>0$.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A008836. It also mentions some equivalence to RH.

Comment: The Dirichlet series of $\phi(s)$ converges at $s=1$ by the prime number theorem. However, you did not ask about the Dirichlet series of $\phi(s)$ but about the analytic function defined by it (and my previous remark was about this analytic function). For example, the Dirichlet series of $\zeta(s)$ diverges for $\Re s<1$, yet $\zeta(s)$ is analytic for $\Re s<1$. All in all I believe you should learn more theory before thinking about these questions. If you did not have a proper course in complex analysis, then start with that. Then, read Titchmarsh's book on the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: $\rho(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(2s)$ on $\Re s >1$ hence everywhere, so not sure what is unclear about it beyond what is unclear about $\zeta$; same about $\phi(s)=\zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$ everywhere (so it is meromorphic in the plane with poles at the non-trivial zeroes of $\zeta$) so not sure again what is unclear about that one either beyond what is unclear about $\zeta$

Comment: @GHf: I realize I did not have any number theory classes during my math college years, yes I have many gaps because of that. I now know more than (say) a week ago, but I still have a long way to go.  I had a standard course on complex numbers (residues, Cauchy-Riemann, analytic continuation, contour integral) but that was 30 years ago).Thanks for the reference.

Comment: In general, it is better to start mathematical research with a lesser known problem. Research and learning goes in small steps. I mean, you don't have to convince yourself that the RH is true, and it is pointless to try your hands at the RH without considerable research expertise. There are many problems about $\zeta(s)$ and related functions that are much easier than the RH, but still would be very valuable to make progress on.

Comment: @GHf: I bought the book you mentioned, and two other ones highly recommended. There is a new question that hesitate to ask because someone might say "this is equivalent to RH". It's about patterns in $\lambda(k)$ (Liouville function). Successive minimum runs (of length $1$) seem to appear 50% of the time. Runs of length $2$ (e.g. a $-1$ followed by $+1, +1$ then $-1$) about 25% of the time, runs of length $3$ about 25% of the time, and so on. I also got Mathematica (trial version) and was able to compute the first million $\lambda(k)$ in less than a minute.

Comment: Statistics of patterns in consecutive values of $\lambda(k)$ is a difficult and active area of research. See arXiv:1509.01545 and arXiv:1904.05096, for example.

Comment: @GHf: Thank you. I will read these articles, and wait for the books I ordered, before posting anything else.